# Riddle: How to change matrix color?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, matrix

There is a matrix M*N. The matrix elements are either black or white. We call neighboring elements of the same color *areas*. You can pick any *area* and *flip* its color (i.e. change the color of all its elements). Given such a matrix find the minimal number of *flips* needed to make the whole matrix either black or white.

**Solution:** It looks like a graph problem. The matrix elements are graph vertices. The vertices are connected iff the correspondent matrix elements are "neighbors" and have the same color. The answer is the number of *connected components* in the graph.

Does it make sense?

**Fixed Solution:** Thanks to @ypercube and @Billiska the solution should be fixed as follows:

- Find the connected components (as in above) and consider a graph of those components.
- Find the graph [center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center), flip it, make a new graph, and repeat until the graph contains only one vertex.

We still have to prove though that flipping the graph center makes the number of flips minimal.

Comment: I think you are close. You only need to change one of the two colours areas.

Comment: Thanks! I have to find the number of "black" and "white" _connected_ _components_ and choose the smallest of both.

Comment: you can do better than that.
consider 1 dimension matrix `(bw)^k b (wb)^k`. ^k means repeated k times. Your algorithm will do 2*k flip = number of white. Whereas if you just keep flipping the middle area, you will solve it in k flips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You proposed the solution:

> It looks like a graph problem. The matrix elements are graph vertices. The vertices are connected iff the correspondent matrix elements are "neighbors" and have the same color. The answer is the number of connected components in the graph.

And the improvement:

> Then one has to find the number of "black" and "white" connected components and choose the smallest of both.

This seems to be quite good but the answer is not so simple as it seems at first. Consider this matrix, where there are 13 Black connected components and 4 White ones. :

```
B w B w B w B w B
w w w w B w w w w
B w B B B B B w B
w w B B B B B w w
B B B B B B B B B  
w w B B B B B w w
B w B B B B B w B
w w w w B w w w w
B w B w B w B w B
```

The minimal solution is only 2 moves though. First flip (to White) the central big Black component. As a result, the flipped one and the 4 white components are now connected into one component. Flip this to Black and all the board is black.

So, the minimal is only 2 moves, not 4, in this case.

So, after you establish, the connected (black and white components), we have a graph of connections between these components (like in @Biliska's answer). Here's the graph for the above matrix:

```
        B
        |
     B--w--B
        |
    B   |   B
    |   |   |
B---w---B---w---B
    |   |   |
    B   |   B
        |
     B--w--B
        |
        B
```

We now need to find the graph's **[center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center)**, or just one of the central points, e.g. a node A where the greatest distance d(A,B) to other nodes B is minimal (and this minimal greatest distance is sometimes called "eccentricity"). It's obvious from the diagram that for the above graph, there is exactly one central point and the "eccentricity" is 2.

When the eccentricity is `n`, there is at least one "maximal" path of length `2n-1` or `2n` (of `2n` or `2n+1` nodes). In our case:

```
B-w-B-w-B
```

Since the nodes are sequentially black and white in any path in these graphs, it's not difficult to prove that the minimal changes needed is exactly `n` (2 in this case) and can be achieved by changing always the central area.

Comment: So, you suggest create a graph of connected components and then repeat flipping a graph center and merging the graph until we get only one component. Is it correct?

Comment: @Michael: exactly. What I don't know is what algorithms exist to find a graph's center.

Comment: You can probably find the graph center trivially: 1) for each vertex `v` find the distances from `v` to all other vertices; 2) count their maximum and call it `d(v)`; 3) now find such `u` that `d(u)` is minimal among all `d(v)`.

Comment: at ypercube, filp the graph centre seems correct, yet I'm struggling to prove it.
@Michael In case you missed it. Finding shortest path between every pair of vertices is O(v^3). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#Algorithms

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved as a [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Model your problem as a state graph `G=(V,E)` where `V = possible states (matrix states)` and `E = { (u,v) | can move from state u to state v with single "flip" }`

Now, once you have the graph - all you have to do is use some shortest path algorithm.

Since the graph is unweighted - you can use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) as your shortest path algorithm. If you can find some [admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) - you might also be able to use [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) - which is expected to be faster with a descent heuristic.

Comment: I would do a search for connected component first then run the path finding algorithm on those component. The only problem here, is that despite the fact that BFS or A* are linear, the number of path is exponential. Might cause some issues on some particular distribution (a diagonal matrix where every element is a single component)

Comment: Thanks. It will work. Now I wonder if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: I can't seem to think of this problem as a shortest path problem. Care to clarify?

Comment: @Billiska: The shortest path is in the state graph. You need to find the shortest path from the initial position to a final position, where each vertex of the graph is a state of the matrix you can get.

Answer (score 3):

First, you are off that trying to model the problem as a connection graph of **cells** when in fact you should model the problem as a connection graph of **areas**

For exapmle

```
b w b w b
w b b w b
w w b b w
```

transformed into area notation as:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 3 3 4 5
6 6 3 3 7
```

which is better represented as:

```
1 - 2   4 - 5
|   | /     |
6 - 3 - - - 7
```

Now the next thing to do is
to repeatedly perform `flip` operation to merge the areas.
I'm not sure if greedily flip the area with **most connections** will be correct or not.

For example I'll flip area 3 first because it has 4 connections. Then I get:

```
1       5
  \   /
   (3)
```

Then flip area 3 again because it has 2 connections:

```
   (3)
```

done

So you can see `flip` operation has the effect of merging all adjacent nodes into the one being flipped.

EDIT: in fact, greedily flip area with most connections isn't optimal.
Take the 1-dimension example I commented earlier.

input:

```
             middle
                v
b w b w b w b w b w b w b w b w b
<---4 times--->   <---4 times--->
```

You can see that the most connections any area has is of degree 2.
But the most efficient algorithm will only choose to flip the middle area.

Comment: Thanks. So, once we find the connected components we can _greedily_ flip the the component of the maximal _degree_ and merge until we get only one component. The question is if this greedy algorithm finds the minimal number of "flips".